# Запрос с nodejs на API написаном на ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, dom

API на ASP.NET отдает мне xml, как вытянуть данные из него на nodejs? 
Пытался конвертнуть xml в json, но из входящих 3 страниц xml я получил 12 страниц json.

Как парсить xml в nodejs?
Подскажите пожалуйста конкретный вариант с примером.

Comment: В nodejs удобнее работать с JSON, поэтому можно "на лету" конвертировать XML в JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007206/how-to-parse-xml-from-url-with-node

Comment: Используйте любой из множества XML-парсеров. Хоть [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) для небольших XML, хоть потоковый [node-expat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat)...

Comment: Yaant, спасибо за Ваш ответ, но xml2js работает неправильно, не конвертит полный xml.
И впринципе конверт xml в json заканчивается преобразованием 3 страниц данных в 12.
Невозможно с ними потом работать.